pylint: missing module docstring. These are the same
I'm using pylint, and it says that there is an issue with my import statement. I follow the link in the preview:
Unable to import 'aws_cdk'PylintE0401:import-error
Import "aws_cdk" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports

which takes me to this page with information on "missing module docstring".
Now, without getting into all of that--my question is about what is on this page:
 pylint.readthedocs - missing module docstring/C0114
I don't see any difference between the problematic code and the correct code other than the comments "# [missing-module-docstring]" and """"Module providing a function printing python version."""". Are these having an effect? What is this page meant to convey?
My particular issue is with importing the aws-cdk. My statement is copied from elsewhere.
from aws_cdk import (
    App,
    Environment,
)

I've looked at the page. (main question)
I've installed requirements.txt

have you selected a python interpreter for your current workspace/workspace folder?  if not then pylance is going to have trouble finding packages.  without that it can only check basic python syntax and maybe builtins.

Your error is an import-error, the associated doc is here: https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/messages/error/import-error.html
In your case, probably:

you're importing a package that is not installed in your environment

"your environment" being the environment where pylint runs.
Not sure why you were linked to another unrelated doc.
